# Are iPhone retina pixels of the same physical dimensions as iPad retina pixels?

Tags: iphone, ipad, screen, dimensions

I'm designing an app that creates graphics for retina displays. One of the benefits I want to offer to the users is that the graphics designed the iPad app would look exactly the same on the iPhone.

However, by eyeballing the results, it seems to me that the physical pixels of iPhone retina display are about 20% smaller smaller than the iPad's one. So the 57x57 pixel space displayed on iPhone and iPad retina displays side by side would appear to have different shape - iPad would be larger.

**I'm interested if there is really a difference in the physical dimensions of retina display pixels, or if it is a bug in my code.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Retina display on iPhone 5:**
1136x640-pixel resolution at 326 ppi

**Ipad (retina):**
2048x1536 resolution at 264 pixels per inch (ppi)

So as you can see the density is higher on the iPhone than the Ipad. From this I would say you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. Those devices use different displays that have different pixels/inch.

iPhone Retina: 326 PPI
iPad Retina: 264 PPI

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Apple